# how to run grails without connecting to the internet

Tags: grails, grails3

how do you run grails3 without connecting to the internet? I had a project in my laptop and want to run it in the computer in my office, the problem is that computer can't connect to the internet right now so it can't download the build for grails. what can I do right now? I tried to download gradle in my laptop and paste to the computer, but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

try with **`grails --offline run-app`** it should do the trick

Comment: im running grails with the angular, so im using "gradlew bootRun --parallel", its automatically download the gradle, but my computer doesn't have any connection